# Tune mechanical disk brakes TRP Spyre C

Tags: disc-brake, sram

On my bike I have SRAM Rival levers paired to TRP Spyre C mechanical disc brake calipers. I'd like to tune them to "brake harder"; currently, I have to press more than half of the way on order to start braking. I can't find any way to do that. I could change that directly on the cable on the brake, but there ought to be a better way.

Comment: Are there any barrel adjusters? Either inline ones on the cable, or on the lever or the brake caliper?

Comment: I can't see any, hence the question.

Comment: TRP Spyre manual says there is a barrel adjuster on the caliper

Comment: https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/mechanical-disc-brake-alignment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable To Adjust Mechanical Disc Brakes Properly](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/43776/unable-to-adjust-mechanical-disc-brakes-properly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I could change that directly on the cable on the brake

I think by that you mean undoing the cable attachment bolt, pulling the cable tight and re-attaching it. You are correct, that's not the way to adjust mechanical disc brakes, unless you have lots of cable slack that needs to be taken out.

Different models of mechanical disc brakes have different adjustment controls, so you should look up the manual for what you have on your bike. The [Kona Rove ST](https://www.konaworld.com/rove_st.cfm) has TRP Spyre C calipers, the manual for which is [here](https://www.trpbrakes.com/userfiles/file/SPYRE_Final_053113%281%29.pdf).

The manual says there is a barrel adjuster on the caliper and a pad adjuster. (I think this moves just the outer pad so you would need to re-align the caliper if you use this adjuster, but you probably need to do that anyway).

Comment: Second the comment about the pad adjuster.  If your brakes were tighter before, and they've worn down, you're increasingly pushing the disc laterally to reach the fixed pad.  This will both increase the required travel in the lever and make your braking a bit mushy, neither of which you want.

Comment: On my promax cable discs you need to adjust the fixed pad approximately every other time you adjust the barrel adjuster, assuming you do that frequently enough that adjustments are fairly small. In this case the OP will almost certainly need to do both. (I like to have my brakes set up quite nicely, not that it did me much good recently)

Comment: @DavidW The TRP Spyre does not have a fixed pad - both pads move in when you brake.